# Is it okay if I use a similar background for an app, when I am building a capstone project?

Tags: android

I am building a smart door lock for my capstone project. I selected a beautiful black wooden finish for my background in the app that I created. However I just came across a smart lock app picture that has a similar black wooden background. Now this is for just a project and not for profit but is it subject to copyright law?